# regexp_extract in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I wanted to use the regexp_extract function in BigQuery. I have some data in a columns that looks like 'x__y', 'a__b' and so on.

This was the SQL that I was trying to use -

```
SELECT
REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, r"(.*)__(.*)", 1, 1) as extracted_value
FROM
TABLE
```

Ideally, for the data point, 'a__b' I would get 'a'. But I keep getting this error -

> regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have
> more than 1 capturing group

I am not sure why I am getting error as I have placed the first occurrence in the function.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of capturing groups in regular expressions? The REGEX_EXTRACT function accepts only one capturing group in the regex, but your regex contains two, as indicated in the error message.

Comment: My bad - I see the error - Returns an error if: The regular expression has more than one capturing group. I am sorry I was confused with this - 

If occurrence is specified, the search returns a specific occurrence of the regexp in value, otherwise returns the first match. If occurrence is greater than the number of matches found, NULL is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REGEX_EXTRACT will throw an error if there are multiple capture groups -

```
Returns an error if:

The regular expression is invalid
The regular expression has more than one capturing group
The position is not a positive integer
The occurrence is not a positive integer
```

Changed the SQL to get around the issue -

```
SELECT
REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, r"(.*)__") as extracted_value
FROM
TABLE
```